# Rounding spoke length calculator results

Tags: wheel-building

The spoke calculator gave me the following results left 292.34 and right 290.98.
I am going to buy DT Swiss Competition spokes which are sold by 2mm increments from [here](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/am/en/dt-swiss-competition-db-silver-spokes-18-pack/rp-prod91857). So which spoke length is better to buy ?

Answer (score 4):

Given that there's a bit of forgiveness thanks to the length of the spoke nipples that the spokes will thread into you could safely round down to Left 292mm and Right 290mm for spoke lengths.

An alternative is just rounding to 292mm for both sides - especially if your rim has recessed spoke holes (as most double wall rims do).

Comment: I also think you're safer to round down. And also, personal opinion, forget about aluminum nipples. They go bad and get 'rounded' much more easily than brass, when they go bad it's a huge pain to replace, and you gain gain what? 40 grams? http://www.bikeforums.net/bicycle-mechanics/286419-wheelbuilders-brass-vs-aluminum-nipples.html

Answer (score 3):

With double wall rims both are fine. Longer gets a bit more thread engagement, if you are using aluminum nipples you probably want it.

With single wall, shorter because you don't want spoke ends poking through rim tape.

Comment: That's right. With longer it is also easier to lace the wheel, the spoke will reach the nipple easier. But this is just a small detail, perhaps only important to novice wheel builders like me.